# Navigation drawer not showing the hamburger icon

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

In the small app, I want to use navigation drawer but neither the left arrow key is working nor hamburger icon... Could you please figure out the problem?

MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.bablu.zoo;

import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.PersistableBundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mActionBarDrawerToggle;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        // For navigation bar
        if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        }
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mActionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.drawer_opened, R.string.drawer_closed){
            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                if(getSupportActionBar() != null)
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.drawer_opened);
                mActionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
                if(getSupportActionBar() != null)
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(R.string.drawer_closed);
                mActionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

            }
        };

        mDrawerLayout.addDrawerListener(mActionBarDrawerToggle);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mActionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
        //Call syncState() from your activity's onPostCreate to set the state of the indicator
        // based on whether the drawerlayout is in open or closed state once the activity
        // has been restored with onRestoreInstanceState.
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mActionBarDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        //When the device is rotated the method 'onConfigurationChanged(newConfig' knows when the drawer is open or close.
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        if(mActionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item))
            return true;

        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

content_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.example.bablu.zoo.MainActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main">

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hello world"/>

        <ListView android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:background="#111"/>


    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.example.bablu.zoo.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Here are the pictures below:

[image]

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your code Add `toolbar`

see this in line

```
 mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
 mActionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.drawer_opened, R.string.drawer_closed)
```

Use this way

```
 mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
     mActionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_opened, R.string.drawer_closed)
```

Comment: Your answer was helpful. Thanks for the prompt reply.

Comment: Oh sorry, I did not know about that but I have done now.

Comment: @BABLUKUMAR Glad to help you.